# iOS: unrecognized selector sent to instance when changing device orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to show a small controller in the middle of the screen on iPad.

```
-(void)showDownloadDialog {


if (self.downloadDialogViewController == nil)
{
    self.downloadDialogViewController = [[DownloadDialogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DownloadDialogViewController" bundle:nil];
}

self.downloadDialogViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);

if(LTIsPhone()) {

    [self presentViewController:_downloadDialogViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    return;
}

if(_darkBackgroundView == nil)
{
    _darkBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _darkBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:0.5];
}

_darkBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
self.downloadDialogViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview:_darkBackgroundView];
[window addSubview:self.downloadDialogViewController.view];}
```

It does appear, but after I flip iPad and try to push any control on the screen, unrecognized selector error happen. My IBActions cannot be found.

```
-[__NSArrayM lowResButtonDidFire:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18a95770
```

When I `presentViewController` everything works flawless, but when I deal with a controller added on view, then the crash happens. How to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you register a notification for "lowResButtonDidFire:" in your code? Are you unregistering before the object gets deallocated?

Comment: Probably means your view controller is getting deallocated but its view is not being removed from the window, so the touch handler in the view is calling to a deallocated object.  You can confirm this by turning on zombies.

Comment: How is `downloadDialogViewController` defined ?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) DownloadDialogViewController *downloadDialogViewController;

Comment: Enabled NSZombies... -[DownloadDialogViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16eb4560